# Limit in fourier's transformation?

Tags: real-analysis

i have this question :

let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, and $F(y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-ixy}f(x)dx$

so my question is :
prove that lim F(y)=0 when $y\rightarrow \infty$ ?

thanks for any answer

Comment: "prove that $\lim_{y\to\infty} F(y)=0$" is not a question.

Comment: Yes..., but you can use Riemann-Lebesgue.

Comment: this is the Riemann Lebesgue lemma. it is based on the idea that $f \in L^1 \cap L^\infty$ means $f$ can be approximated by smooth functions with compact supports, or step functions with compact supports (step functions are simpler in my opinion)